# where to use FM modifier in formatting field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
SELECT to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD'), 
       to_date(substring(data,185,8), 'YYYYMMDD'),
       to_date(substring(data,193,8), 'YYYYMMDD'),
       to_date(substring(data,201,8), 'YYYYMMDD'),
       to_timestamp(substring(data,31,19), 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS') 
FROM temp_table
WHERE substring(data,74,2)='H1';
```

this is the code from mload where im getting error

```
ERROR:  source string too short for "YYYY" formatting field  
DETAIL:  Field requires 4 characters, but only 0 remain.  
HINT:  If your source string is not fixed-width, try using the "FM" modifier.
```

Comment: are you sure about the index in this substring? to_timestamp(substring(data,31,19),'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS')

Comment: yeah those are the fixed width for particular column,the problem is with  to_date(substring(data,193,8), 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: **[edit]** your question  and show us the data stored in the column `data`.  [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting would be most easily explained by the substrings not matching a valid date - e.g you think your substring is returning '20180716', but it's not.

First thing you should do is check the formatting of your 'data' string and make sure the dates and timestamp matches what you think it does - i.e. is it exactly 19 characters after position 31 in your string? Try selecting the substrings you are trying to convert and make sure it actually matches what you expect.

**However**, I would say your approach here is very risky. Are you 100% positive the string will return the same value every time, with all your dates in the same position? I would have offered an alternative example using a regex, but without knowing what the 'data' string looks like, I'm unable to validate an answer. **A sample of the 'data' string would be helpful to offer a better solution.**

Comment: to_date(substring(data,193,8), 'YYYYMMDD') here from 193-201 i have null value in the data

Comment: 20180713        20180720...this is the sample data that i can share with you.....here it strts from 185 and end at 209.(193-201 is null having 8 spaces),(201-209 has a date with exact 8 characters)

Comment: @harshikap I'm sorry, but that doesn't really help. You can use a regex to pull out every pattern that matches 8 consecutive numbers, which might pull out all your dates regardless of index positions, but might not be a valid solution for you if you have other dates or numbers in the string that match that pattern. I suspect your timestamp is the part causing the trouble but without a full sample I can't investigate this any further for you.